# Postgres: How to convert column type from string to integer with default value?

Tags: postgresql

New to postgres.

I have a column called "customer_id" in Postgres currently defined as "character varying".

Looking in the DB, a lot of the rows have NULL.

I need this column to be an INTEGER with possible NULL value.
How can I do that in postgres?

I tried running query :

```
 alter table leads alter column customer_id type INTEGER using CAST("customer_id" as INTEGER);
```

But I get an error saying:

```
 default for column "customer_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
```

Comment: check http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/29-How-to-convert-a-table-column-to-another-data-type.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understood, you need cast "character varying" column to INTEGER.

It seems that you have default value for this "character varying" column and postgres can't "attach" that value for `INTEGER` type.

If so, you can first drop default value, convert column to INTEGER and add default value appropriate for `INTEGER` type. like this:

```
alter table leads alter customer_id drop default;

alter table leads alter column customer_id type INTEGER using CAST("customer_id" as INTEGER);

alter table leads alter customer_id set default <YOUR DEFAULT VALUE HERE>;
```